# How to properly use slash command in selfbot DISCORD discum library

Tags: python, discord

I can’t understand how I can use the slash command in the self bot through the Discum library.
I'm trying to run the work command, but it doesn't work.
Here is the code:

```
import discum  
from discum.utils.slash import SlashCommander


bot = discum.Client(token='TOKEN', log=False)

def slashCommand(resp, guildID, channelID, botID):
    if resp.event.ready_supplemental:
        bot.gateway.request.searchSlashCommands(guildID, limit=1, query='work')
        
    if resp.event.guild_application_commands_updated:
        bot.gateway.removeCommand(slashCommand)
        slashCmds = resp.parsed.auto()['application_commands']
        s = SlashCommander(slashCmds, application_id=botID)
        data = s.get(['work'])
        mes = bot.triggerSlashCommand(botID, channelID=channelID, guildID=guildID, data=data)
        print('command send')
        print(mes)

guildID = "922563182445359134"
channelID = "928054502332969010"
botID = "928062872838352956"
bot.gateway.command(
    {
        "function": slashCommand,
        "params": {"guildID": guildID, "channelID": channelID, "botID": botID},
    }
)

bot.gateway.run()
```

Who can help?
Thanks in advance

ps. [link to official example](https://github.com/Merubokkusu/Discord-S.C.U.M/blob/master/examples/slashcommands.py)

UPDATE: Sends global commands calmly, but server commands give a response of 400, how to fix it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.